# LUA Error attempt to compare number to nil

Tags: lua

Need help with code that generates lots of errors:

```
function()
    local restedxp = GetXPExhaustion()
    local totalXP =  UnitXPMax("player")
    local percent = 0
    if restedxp > 0 then percent = floor((restedxp / totalXP)  * 100) end
    
    local ret = string.format("%s%%", percent)
    return ret
end
```

Error: attempt to compare number to nil

Comment: You should include the full error in your post, lua errors usually look like `somefile.lua:1: attempt to compare number with nil`. your error is likely due to `GetXPExhaustion()` returning nil, your check should probably just be `if restedxp then` but i am not sure what your environment is.

Comment: It a Weakaura for World of Warcraft and you are right. The error only appears when GetXPExhaustion() is zero. I removed >0 and it works. Im obviously not a programmer. I just like to fiddle around in other peoples work and see how things work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing a number vs nil doesn't make sense. Hence the error.

In your case you only have one comparison in the provided code which is any expression with a [relational operator](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.4).

The usual thing you do is to find out which of the two values is nil and fix the reason or if you can't avoid that value being nil make sure you only do the comparison if it is not.

In your case this is pretty simple. You go to the line number which is given in the error message. You find the only conditional expression `restedxp > 0` and as `0` is obviously a number it must be `restedxp` that is `nil`

You find out where restedxp is assigned the last value befor the comparison which is

```
local restedxp = GetXPExhaustion()
```

So `GetXPEhaustion()` returns `nil`!
If you have access to that function you may be able to fix it or at least find out if you can do anything so it won't return `nil`!

If you can't you either assign a default value to `restedxp`, for example `0`.

```
local restedxp = GetXPExhaustion() or 0
```

Or you avoid to compare the values with a conditional statement.

```
if type(restedxp) == "number" and restedxp > 0 then
  percent = restedXp // totalXP * 100
end
```

Or if you know restedxp is either a number or nil

```
if restedxp and restedxp > 0 then
  percent = restedXp // totalXP * 100
end
```

The same makes sense for `totalXP` of course. Just also make sure it isn't `0` befor you divide.

Your string formatting is incorrect btw.

percent is a number so you should use `%d` instead of `%s` as `%s` refers to a string. It will work as Lua will convert your number to a string but it's not very clean.

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.format

> Option s expects a string; if its argument is not a string, it is
> converted to one following the same rules of tostring. If the option
> has any modifier (flags, width, length), the string argument should
> not contain embedded zeros.

Comment: Thanks alot for explaining. That was very helpful, not to mention a clever solution. : )